# Throwing an exception from std::call_once

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, mutex, std

The C++ Standard states the following about the execution of `std::call_once` with functions that throw exceptions (§30.4.4.2/2):

> 2/ Effects: An execution of call_once that does not call its func is a passive execution. An execution of call_once that calls its func is an active execution. An active execution shall call INVOKE (DECAY_- COPY ( std::forward(func)), DECAY_COPY (std::forward(args))...). **If such a call to func throws an exception the execution is exceptional, otherwise it is returning. An exceptional execution shall propagate the exception to the caller of call_once.** Among all executions of call_once for any given once_flag: at most one shall be a returning execution; if there is a returning execution, it shall be the last active execution; and there are passive executions only if there is a returning execution. [ Note: passive executions allow other threads to reliably observe the results produced by the earlier returning execution. — end note ]

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and running the following code:

```
void f(){
    throw std::exception( "Catch me!" );
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
    once_flag flag;
    try{
        call_once( flag, f );
    } catch( const std::exception& e ){
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My result is: the code in the catch block runs and prints the message, but when the program exists I get a call to `abort()` and the following message printed to cout:

> ...\mutex.c(38) mutex destroyed while busy

Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: No, it's a bug, the program should work fine (although you're using a non-standard constructor for `std::exception`, in ISO C++ you can only default construct `std::exception`, that causes frequent portability issues when MSVC users check incode that's meant to compile on other implementations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this supposed to happen?

No, not really. This is a **bug**.

However, notice the fact that VC11 is not alone on this:

- Intel ICC 13.0.1 calls `std::terminate()` as if your exception was not handled (see [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4sAas7%2440));
- GCC 4.8.0 beta probably does something similar, but it does not show any output, it just swallows the exception and silently terminates the program (see [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4sAas7%2439)). [**UPDATE: This bug does not seem to be reproducible in other enviroments and is likely to be an issue with the configuration on liveworkspace.org only**]

GCC 4.7.2 and Clang 3.2, on the other hand, behave correctly.

By the way, it is worth noticing that the C++ Standard (Paragraph 18.8.1) specifies that `std::exception` [only has a default constructor and a copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception). The constructor you are using is most likely a non-portable MS extension.

You may consider using `std::logic_error` instead, which derives from `std::exception` and supports a constructor accepting a string.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware std::exception only has a default and copy constructor, I'm actually using custom exceptions in the original code. I'll refrain from throwing exceptions out of call_once for now, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It is also worth noting when `call_once` returns with an exception, it isn't considered satisfied.  I.e. the next time the `call_once` is executed, `f` will be attempted again.  And so on, until `f` returns without throwing an exception.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Good observation, thank you for mentioning that.

Comment: G++ 4.8 WORKSFORME, dunno what's wrong with liveworkspace. Note that you probably need compile with `-pthread` but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Is it the same build? (20130224)

Comment: I tried with 20130225 and the tip of the trunk, with three different `--enable-libstdcxx-time` configurations, and all work correctly. The `call_once` code hasn't changed since 4.7 anyway.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: OK, thank you for testing. I will edit the answer

Comment: I'll have to try and figure out what platform liveworkspace is using and if there's a GCC problem, and also which std::lib their Intel compiler uses, as that's probably libstdc++ too

Comment: I tried on Mac OS with g++ 4.7.2 and the first thread throws and catch happens. However the program coredumps before a second thread even starts. Has anybody observed the same behavior?

Comment: Call of `std::terminate` reproduced on a RedHat server with a custom build of g++ 6.2.0. The call chain was `__gthread_once` → `clear_once_control` → `_Unwind_Resume` → `_Unwind_RaiseException_Phase2` → `__gxx_persernality_v0` → `__cxa_call_terminate`. Still not sure the reason.