# Protobuf crashes on initialization

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm totally in the dark as to why this is happening. Same code runs perfectly fine on windows. Compiles fine to ubuntu linux with gcc 7.3.0 and protobuf version 3.6.1. I built it using vcpkg and used the compiled protoc to generate .cc and and .h files from my .proto file. Yet, when I start the app, it immediately crashes. Here's the stack trace.

```
0  0x00007ffff70e3e97  __GI_raise  /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c  51
1  0x00007ffff70e5801  __GI_abort  /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/stdlib/abort.c  79
2  0x00007ffff7ad88b7  ??    
3  0x00007ffff7adea06  ??    
4  0x00007ffff7adea41  std::terminate()    
5  0x00007ffff7adec74  __cxa_throw    
6  0x00007ffff7ada979  ??    
7  0x0000555555597655  std::call_once<void (&)()>  /usr/include/c++/7/mutex  698
8  0x0000555555594c34  google::protobuf::internal::call_once<std::once_flag&, void (&)()>  /home/ubuntu/Documents/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/google/protobuf/stubs/once.h  91
9  0x00005555555898a8  protobuf_ProtoCombined_2eproto::AddDescriptors  /home/ubuntu/Documents/fastobjtobinary/ProtoCombined.pb.cc  249
10  0x0000555555594141  protobuf_ProtoCombined_2eproto::StaticDescriptorInitializer::StaticDescriptorInitializer  /home/ubuntu/Documents/fastobjtobinary/ProtoCombined.pb.cc  254
11  0x0000555555591ad6  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0  /home/ubuntu/Documents/fastobjtobinary/MyProtoCombined.pb.cc  256
12  0x0000555555591aec  _GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN13ProtoCombined33_BinaryMeshFull_default_instance_E  /home/ubuntu/Documents/fastobjtobinary/ProtoCombined.pb.cc  2540
13  0x00005555556ecfcd  __libc_csu_init    
14  0x00007ffff70c6b28  __libc_start_main  /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/csu/../csu/libc-start.c  266
15  0x000055555556892a  _start
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Any code to try and reproduce a problem? My blind guess: check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311469/throwing-an-exception-from-stdcall-once)

Comment: Did you ever fixed this problem? I am hitting something similar.

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember what I did to fix it. Probably deleted everything and recompiled.